# Stress testing a desktop app system

Tags: testing

If I want to stress test a 'classic' client-server (desktop app <-> LAN <-> database server) Windows Forms desktop application to see how it performs when many concurrent PC users are using it, how should I go about it? I want to simulate many PC users concurrently going through a work flow, to see if it all stands up and at what point the system degrades unacceptably.  I've looked at many test tools but they all seems to be skewed toward testing functionality or web app performance, which is quite different.

Clearly having many actual people on actual PCs is not practical, and lots of virtual machines on a few PCs is not representative either. 'Cloud' computing (EC2, Azure etc) looks promising but the documentation and pricing information all seems to be skewed towards mobile apps or web servers, again not the same (but that could just be presentation so I remain open to the idea). I need to be able to virtualise a small LAN of many client machines running the application and a database server.

Can anyone suggest how to do this, or recommend something?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the real question is - do you really need to do performance testing in your case? Consider this - where is your business and functional logic?

Performance testing of Desktop applications is oxymoron by itself. Desktop application is made to be used by one person at a time. So if getting a response  takes 5 seconds, it will take (pretty much) 5 seconds no matter how many users are clicking the button. The only real thing close to your backend is the DB and they by design support serious asynchronous load. In case this is not enough - just make a cluster.

Comment: Yes I do (need to do etc). The point is that I need to do the tests to prove that the system overall is robust and responsive under load - not just the desktop app part. If one desktop app client gets a response of 'n' seconds there is no guarantee it will get the same response when 500 similar clients are busy on the same system, because that will depend inter alia on database design etc etc. It's the overall performance under load that is under scrutiny. Hence my question.